# How do I represent domain knowledge information with bnlearn

Tags: r, directed-acyclic-graphs, bayesian-networks, causality, bnlearn

I am learning about Dynamic Bayesian Network models using the R package `bnlearn`. To this end, I am following [this paper](https://bmcbioinformatics.biomedcentral.com/articles/10.1186/s12859-019-2692-x) where they impose certain constraints in the form of 6 layers (Table 1 in the paper):

```
1   Gender, age at ALS onset    
2   Onset site, onset delta (start of the trial - onset)    
3   Riluzole intake, placebo/treatment  
4   Variables at time t-1   
5   Variables at time t, TSO    
6   Survival
```

In this example, since `gender` and `age` are in the top layer they cannot be influenced by `Riluzole intake` but influence (or have a causal connection) `Riluzole intake` and ultimately `survival`. This guarantees acyclicality in the network, that is, we do not have non-ending feedback loops among the variables.

My question is, how can we model such prior knowledge using the R package `bnlearn`.

Comment: If you want to specify the network structure and parameters using domain knowledge, you can build the network manually using `custom.fit`. If you want to estimate the structure from data then you can impose constraints on edge direction & presence using the `whitelist` and `blacklist` parameters in the structure learning algorithms.

Comment: thanks for the answer @user20650, if you want to place the answer I can mark it as answered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add domain knowledge or constraints to structure learning in a couple of ways.

- If you want to specify the network structure and parameters using domain knowledge, you can build the network manually using `custom.fit`.
- If you want to estimate the structure of the BN from data then you can impose constraints on edge direction & edge presence using the `whitelist` and `blacklist` parameters in the structure learning algorithms.
- A prior can be placed on the edges in structure learning (e.g. `prior="cs"`, where "*If prior is cs, beta is a data frame with columns from, to and prob specifying the prior probability for a set of arcs. A uniform probability distribution is assumed for the remaining arcs.*"). [There are other priors that can be used.](https://www.bnlearn.com/documentation/man/score.html)